# PHP filter_input validate INT

Tags: php, filter

I have this chunk of code:

```
$range = array (
    'options' => array (
        'min_range' => 0,
        'max_range' => 10
    )
);

if (!$number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $range)) {
    exit ('Error');
}
```

The "number" input will be sent from a  with options from 0 to 10.

the problem is that if number = 0 this returns "Error".

What's wrong with that?

Thanks

Comment: This is [operator precedence](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): You first assign the result of the function call to `$number` and then you negate that result converting it to boolean (it could have been boolean, int or NULL).

Answer (score 8):

This is because `!0` is true. Why? By adding the `!` you are doing a boolean check, so your variable gets converted. And according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the integer `0` (zero)
> - the float `0.0` (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string `"0"`
> - ...

So the integer `0` gets converted to `false` while all other integers are converted to `true`.

This is why you need to do a [type safe check](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for `false` or `null` as these are the values `filter_input()` returns if it fails for some reason.

```
$number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $range);
if ($number === false) {
    //filter failed
}
if ($number === null) {
    //variable was not set
}
```

Comment: but what's the difference between 0 and other numbers as they are all in the same range?

Comment: @medk Is there something wrong with this answer? Of course you can do both checks in one `if()` if you are just looking for an unspecific error

Comment: this solution also works with filter_var() http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
if (
    !$number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $range) === 0 
    || !filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $range) === FALSE) 
{
    exit ('Error');
}
```

Comment: You're over-complicating things here. And you're doing the same operation two times albeit you already store the result (at least you tried to, problem with these complicated constructs is that they fail easily) to the variable. @kingkero has some very valid points in his answer, you should try to adopt those. If you want to pull all into the if condition, there is a way to do that, it starts with `if (FALSE === ...) {`. Good luck!